# How do you create a generic function in Rust with a trait requiring a lifetime?

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

I am trying to write a trait which works with a database and represents something which can be stored. To do this, the trait inherits from others, which includes the `serde::Deserialize` trait.

```
trait Storable<'de>: Serialize + Deserialize<'de> {
    fn global_id() -> &'static [u8];
    fn instance_id(&self) -> Vec<u8>;
}

struct Example {
    a: u8,
    b: u8
}

impl<'de> Storable<'de> for Example {
    fn global_id() -> &'static [u8] { b"p" }
    fn instance_id(&self) -> Vec<u8> { vec![self.a, self.b] }
}
```

Next, I am trying to write this data using a generic function:

```
pub fn put<'de, S: Storable>(&mut self, obj: &'de S) -> Result<(), String> {
    ...
    let value = bincode::serialize(obj, bincode::Infinite);
    ...
    db.put(key, value).map_err(|e| e.to_string())
}
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
--> src/database.rs:180:24
    |
180 |     pub fn put<'de, S: Storable>(&mut self, obj: &'de S) -> Result<(), String> {
    |                        ^^^^^^^^ expected lifetime parameter
```

[Minimal example on the playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=94501043315e9b78718af49a5d3aac91&version=stable)

How would I resolve this, possibly avoid it altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined `Storable` with a generic parameter, in this case a lifetime. That means that the generic parameter has to be propagated throughout the entire application:

```
fn put<'de, S: Storable<'de>>(obj: &'de S) -> Result<(), String> { /* ... */ }
```

You can also decide to make the generic specific. That can be done with a concrete type or lifetime (e.g. `'static`), or by putting it behind a trait object.

Serde also has [a comprehensive page about deserializer lifetimes](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html). It mentions that you can choose to use `DeserializeOwned` as well.

```
trait Storable: Serialize + DeserializeOwned { /* ... */ }
```

You can use the same concept as `DeserializeOwned` for your own trait as well:

```
trait StorableOwned: for<'de> Storable<'de> { }

fn put<'de, S: StorableOwned>(obj: &'de S) -> Result<(), String> {
```

Answer (score 4):

You have the `'de` lifetime in the wrong place -- you need it to specify the argument to `Storable`, not the lifetime of the reference `obj`.

Instead of

```
fn to_json<'de, S: Storable>(obj: &'de S) -> String {
```

use

```
fn to_json<'de, S: Storable<'de>>(obj: &S) -> String {
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=563c5c0397e22634ef186e903300ad1b&version=undefined).

The lifetime of `obj` doesn't actually matter here, because you're not returning any values derived from it. All you need to prove is that `S` implements `Storable<'de>` for some lifetime `'de`.

If you want to eliminate the `'de` altogether, you should use `DeserializeOwned`, as [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46654539/3650362) describes.